# How to firebase deploy through Bitbucket Pipeline?

Tags: firebase, angular-cli, webdeploy, firebase-tools, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using angular-cli project and I used Heroku for CD integration. And the repository is on Bitbucket.
Now I am going to use firebase deploy service through Bithubcket pipeline, so I tried as below.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mail-activator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^2.0.5",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "firebase": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.9.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-sweetalert2": "0.0.8",
    "ngx-validators": "^3.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.6.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "~7.0.22",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

and This is Bitbucket pipeline script.

```
image: node:7.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm run postinstall
          - npm run deploy
```

I tried this, but it says

```
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

I am not sure if the bitbucket pipe line uses docker or some container? On Travis we installed firebase-tools as global. 
`npm install -g firebase-tools`

But I am not sure it will works on bitbucket pipeline.

Any helps are welcomed.

Comment: Do you have the firebase-functions package listed in your `package.json`? It should look something like this: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/package.json#L6

Answer (score 10):

Try using another image. There's an example that uses [both angular cli and firebase tool](https://hub.docker.com/r/gabrielaraujof/angular-cli/~/dockerfile/) for it. So you do something like:

```
image: gabrielaraujof/angular-cli

pipelines:
 default:
   - step:
    script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
      - npm install
      - ng build
      - ng test --watch=false
      - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --project project-name-firebase --non-interactive
```

You get the "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" on firebasetool by running:

```
firebase login:ci
```

Save it on bit bucket's Environment variables(Settings > Environment variables) and run the pipeline

Comment: is this a complete example?

Comment: Yes, it is. At least that's what I did a few months ago. Is there any problem?  If doesn't worked, let me know and I can help.

Comment: One update, to add in functions add a line in the script: -npm install --prefix functions